# Cartesian grid across 3D plot

Tags: plotting, mesh

I have a plot of a tennis racket hitting a tennis ball

```
sur[r_, phi_] := {1.4*r*Sin[phi], r*Sin[phi]*Cos[phi], 0};
gauss[x_, y_] := {0, 0, 1/5*Exp[-((x - 0.6)^2 + (y/1.5)^2)/0.02]};
handle = ParametricPlot3D[{u, 0, 0}, {u, 0, -0.2}, PlotStyle -> {Black, Thickness[0.007]}];
surfacegraph = ParametricPlot3D[sur[r, phi] + gauss[r*Sin[phi], r*Cos[phi]], {r, 0, 1}, {phi, 0,Pi}];
boundary = ParametricPlot3D[sur[1, phi], {phi, 0, Pi}, PlotStyle -> {Black, Thickness[0.007]}];
Show[handle, surfacegraph, boundary, PlotRange -> {{-0.5, 2}, {-0.6, 0.6}, {0, 0.3}},PlotRangeClipping -> False, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False]
```

How can I draw a Cartesian mesh on the racket? I tried playing around with FaceGrid, but could not make it work.

[image]

Comment: @kglr Works indeed. Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the options `MeshFunctions {# &, #2 &, #3 &}` and `Mesh -> 10` when you create `surfacegraph`:

```
surfacegraph = ParametricPlot3D[sur[r, phi] + gauss[r*Sin[phi], r*Cos[phi]],
   {r, 0, 1}, {phi, 0, Pi}, 
   MeshFunctions -> {# &, #2 &, #3 &}, Mesh -> 10];

Show[handle, surfacegraph, boundary, 
  PlotRange -> {{-0.5, 2}, {-0.6, 0.6}, {0, 0.3}}, 
  PlotRangeClipping -> False, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, 
  ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

**Note:** Default setting for the option `MeshFunctions` for `ParametricPlot3D` is `{#4&}` or `{#4&, #5&}`.